# Dúvida em diagrama de classe

Tags: classes, diagrama

estou desenvolvendo meu diagrama de classe de um projeto e fiquei com a seguinte dúvida:
[image: Diagrama de Classe]

Como eu indico que somente o ADM pode cadastrar um contribuinte?
Tenho que indicar já isso no Diagrama de Classe?
Obrigado

Tem algum método pra conseguir visualizar as classes que posso ter? Porque nessa fase me sinto meio perdido por não sabe se o que eu penso é uma classe ou não! Obrigado!

Comment: Salvo engano `ADM pode cadastrar um contribuinte` seria função do diagrama de caso de uso. Com o diagrama de caso de uso fica mais fácil definir as classes, assim, você não fica `meio perdido por não sabe se o que eu penso é uma classe ou não`.

Comment: Te entendo cara... É que meu Caso de Uso também não tá dos melhores.. Vou ter que refazer ou implementá-los! Vlw pela dica @rubStackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste seu caso não se faz necessário esta representação no `diagrama de classes`, pois essa mesma representação poderá ser feita no diagrama de `Máquina de Estados`. Pois não vou te afirmar com 100% de certeza, mas creio que o diagrama de classes não tem recursos para este procedimentos, então fiz algumas pequenas modificações no de classes e possível representação de máquinas de estados.

**1. Diagrama de Classe**

Neste foi adicionado um novo `atributo` referente ao `tipo de usuário` se vai ser `comum ou administrador`, bem como os métodos para `CRUD` e somente uma anotação referente a restrição de somente o administrador pode fazer o cadastro do contribuinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2. Diagrama de Máquina de Estados**

Na representação do diagrama de máquinas de estados é representado o cadastro do contribuinte, onde será analisado o `tipo` de usuário, caso ele seja `administrador` será realizado o cadastro do contribuinte e logo após finalizado o processo, se o usuário for do tipo `comum` será então tido o processo como finalizado já que ele não pode realizar este procedimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Devo fazer uma pequena anotação referente ao relacinamento de Contribuinte com Usuario, onde o Contribuinte é na verdade uma herança de Usuario.

Comment: Matou a pau Joaquim... me esclareceu muita coisa, tenho que ser mais específicos nas classes! Não sei se a professora exigirá o Máquina de Estados... mas mesmo assim ajuda a entender o processo!
Obrigado pelo help! Abração!